# Are affine semiring schemes equivalent to semirings?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

One of the generalizations of algebraic geometry is provided by the theory of semiring schemes, cf. [Lorscheid 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3261). The theory follows the same set up of scheme theory, but we use semirings instead of rings.

Given a semiring $R$, we have a semiringed space $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, defined by mimicking the usual definition for rings. This gives a functor $\mathrm{Spec}$ from the opposite of the category semirings to that of affine semiring schemes.

Conversely, there's also a global sections functor $\Gamma:\mathrm{AffSemiSch}^\circ\to\mathrm{Semiring}$ sending a semiringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ to $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Does the pair $(\mathrm{Spec},\Gamma)$ give as in ordinary algebraic geometry a contravariant equivalence of categories $\mathrm{Semiring}\cong\mathrm{AffSemiSch}^\circ$?

Comment: Crossposted: [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224190). See Zhen Lin's comment there.

Comment: @ZhenLin's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224190/are-affine-semiring-schemes-equivalent-to-semirings#comment8772017_4224190) referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403289/are-affine-semiring-schemes-equivalent-to-semirings#comment1032665_403289).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thesis Algebraic geometry over semi-structures and hyper-structures of characteristic one by Jaiung Jun [accessible here](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/bitstream/handle/1774.2/37850/JUN-DISSERTATION-2015.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) gives half of the proof in proposition 2.2.6, the remaining half being easy.

It states that $\mathrm{Spec}:\mathrm{Semiring}\to\mathrm{AffSemiSch}^\circ$ is fully faithful. Since it is essentially surjective by construction, it is an equivalence of categories.

Also $\Gamma(\mathrm{Spec}(R),\mathscr{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(R)})\cong R$ by construction, and $\mathrm{Spec}$ is left adjoint to $\Gamma$ by the usual proof ([here is one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1526426)). So since $\Gamma$ is right adjoint to an equivalence of categories, it follows that $\Gamma$ itself must be an equivalence, and therefore $\mathrm{Spec}$ and $\Gamma$ are mutually inverse.

---

Edit: a better reference is [Čech cohomology of semiring schemes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869317302132), item (3) of proposition 2.1, which explicitly states "The opposite category of affine semiring schemes is equivalent to the category of semirings."!

Comment: See also Con's cautionary note [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224190/are-affine-semiring-schemes-equivalent-to-semirings/4247601?noredirect=1#comment8829762_4247601) regarding Jun's thesis.